# Lazy stream are evaluated all in one moment?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I understand that if I have a lazy stream from a list, (for example a filter)  the check for the condition don't begin until I start the iteration on the stream.

But I want to ask  - when I started the iteration, is the stream iterating all the list, check the condition, and put all the results in an "inner list". in one moment and then start the iteration and gives me the elements in the inner list, or when it starts the iteration it will check only for the first element; and during the iteration it will check for each element at his time.

Also I want to ask if it depends if it is a parallel or not.

(I saw multiple question in this site with the topic of "when lazy stream iterate", but not this particular question - if it iterate at once are little by little, so don't mark it duplicate until you see if it is the exact same question)

EDIT 3 (edit the example to be clear)- 
for example:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
        list.add(i);//fill the list with integers

    Iterator<Integer> iterator=list.stream().filter(j->j%2==0).iterator();

    iterator.next();
```

if in the last line it will take several time to find the first element or not.

Comment: @dima I am coming from this question... there are axplanation in general that tha lazy stream don't iterate imediatly, but not explain if - when it iterate - it iterate all at once or bit by bit during the iteration

Comment: I suppose I don't quite understand your question.  Streams are not just limited to collections, which are finite - they can also come from an infinite source.  Are you asking if the stream can terminate early or if it does some sort of early exit while processing?

Comment: @Makoto I'm asking how it works with collections, if all the collection is iterate once before I get any element, or it iterate only one element

Comment: @gits you're write' I certainly missing some thing here!

Comment: Your question is really unclear. What problem are you trying to solve? What do you want to understand?

Comment: I must say...that is probably the wonkiest enhanced-for loop I've ever seen.  You could accomplish the *same* thing if you just did `for(Integer i : list)`.  That said, your premise is also unclear - are you trying to see if each element is iterated over first, or if the entire stream is processed?  I can't see iteration *except* it in some kind of increment.

Comment: To answer you specific question, your invocation of `next()` will take almost no time as the first element already fulfills the condition. But you may insert a printing statement as in the suggested answer to *see* it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily answer questions like this for yourself with a little bit of coding. Try something like this for example:

```
  List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
   .stream()
   .peek(i -> System.out.println("Peek 1: " + i))
   .filter( i -> i  < 10)
   .peek(i -> System.out.println("Peek 2: " + i))
   .map (i -> String.valueOf(i))
   .peek(i -> System.out.println("Peek 3: " + i))
   .map (i -> Integer.parseInt(i))
   .peek(i -> System.out.println("Peek 4: " + i))
   .filter( i -> i < 10)
   .peek(i -> System.out.println("Peek 5: " + i))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Run it and see if it makes sense.

Comment: OK I tried something like this, and I think I understand better